# How to create simple DataGridComboboxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to create simple DataGridComboboxColumn?

I try to create a row with two fields: string and combobox with some parameters. 
I can hardcode it.

But, it not work. When i click to button "Add Row": row created, but i can edit only text box and no combobox shows.

```
  <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="95*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToolBar  Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="27" >
                        <Button x:Name="btAddAttr"  Click="btAddAttr_Click"  Height="22" Width="22"
                                    ToolTip="Add Row}" 
                                >
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="/UI.Resources;component/PNGImages/ItemAdd.png"></Image>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="btDelAttr"  Click="btDelAttr_Click"  Height="22" Width="22"                                                        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                                    ToolTip="Remove Row"
                                    >
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="/UI.Resources;component/PNGImages/ItemDel.png">
                                </Image>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="grAttrs"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                             
                          >                            
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="dgAttfs"
                                  IsEnabled="True"
                                  IsReadOnly="False"
                                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                  Loaded="dgAttfs_Loaded"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsViewModel.AttributeRowColl,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="120" Width="Auto"  
                                                    Header="Name" />
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="typeAttributeColumn" MinWidth="220"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=TypeAttribute}"                                        
                                    Header="List of types"                                                           
                                                        >
                                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                                        <col:ArrayList>
                                            <sys:String>Type1</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type2</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type3</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type4</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type5</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type6</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type7</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>Type8</sys:String>
                                        </col:ArrayList>
                                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>                                                                               
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>                                    
                            </DataGrid.Columns>                                                                                              
                        </DataGrid>                             
                    </Grid>                        
                </Grid>
```

There is a part of XAML code. So, i try to bind a collection of types with XAML-style,as you can see at code.
And, i try to bind it when `DataGrid` is load.

```
  private void dgAttfs_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> ss = new List<string>();
        ss.Add("Test");
        typeAttributeColumn.ItemsSource = ss;
    }
```

With no result.

And, when button clicks:

```
 private void btAddAttr_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = new Row(_sm);
        _viewModel.ObjectsViewModel.AttributeRowColl.Add(obj);
        typeAttributeColumn.ItemsSource = _viewModel.ObjectsViewModel.AttributeRowColl;
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
```

Class Row:

```
   internal class Row:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IServiceManager _serviceManager;

    private string _name;
    /// <summary>
    /// Имя Значения
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<String> _typesColl;
    public ObservableCollection<String> TypesColl
    {
        get
        {
            if (_typeAttribute == null)
                _typeAttribute = "Bit";

            return _typesColl;
        }

        set
        {
            _typesColl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TypesColl");
        }
    } 

    private String _typeAttribute;
    public String TypeAttribute
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeAttribute;
        }

        set
        {
            _typeAttribute = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TypeAttribute");
        }
    }



    public Row(IServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        _serviceManager = serviceManager;
        TypesColl = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        TypesColl = GetColl(serviceManager);           
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (null != eh)
        {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    }
```

Can you help me, how to show a list of types at DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: perhaps due to ReadOnly property being set to true?

Comment: No,it does not work.

Comment: @AdmiralLand : Remove IsReadOnly="True" from DataGridComboBoxColumn XAML and double click on combo box column .You will get combo box. I am getting combo box using your code.

Comment: @NareshRavlani, post it as answer and i will commit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove IsReadOnly="True" from DataGridComboBoxColumn XAML and double click on combo box column. You will get combo box. I am getting combo box using your code.

This is because data grid has text block as cell template and when you try to edit it using double click,it changes cell template into Edit Cell Template and data grid edit template uses combo box as it's inner control.

Comment: I am not being greedy but if this is what you are looking for then you should mark this as answer as well. So that some one looking for solution can find it easily :)